# OpenCSV all of the data storing in single line version (5.1) and data loss

Tags: java, maven, file, csv, opencsv

Hi while saving object by using openCsv the data getting stored in a single line and if i try to add more than one object the data getting deleted of the previous object. please if anyone knows the solution answer it here.

```
public final Logger log=Logger.getLogger("Error");
    public void beanToCsvExport(final T object, final String filePath) {
        if(object == null) {
            log.warning("Initialization of object failed");
        }else {
            try {
                Writer writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
                StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
                beanToCsv.write(object);
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } catch (CsvDataTypeMismatchException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            } catch (CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to write more than one object the last one is overwritten because the FileWriter you are passing to `StatefulBeanToCsv` is not in append mode. You should specify the append mode in the FileWriter constructor.

```
Writer writer = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
beanToCsv.write(object);
writer.close();
```

Edit: This should solve multiple columns headers and column header not breaking line. It works for me.

```
public <T> void beanToCsvExport(final List<T> object, final String filePath) {
    if (object == null) {
        System.out.println("Initialization of object failed");
    } else {
        try {
            cleanFile(filePath);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath, true);
            StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer).build();
            beanToCsv.write(object);
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException | CsvDataTypeMismatchException | CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The function that resets the file:

```
public void cleanFile(String path) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(path); //Open as non-append to delete all data.
    writer.write("");
    writer.close();
}
```

To test the functions:

```
public void employeesToCsv() {
    List<Employee> list = Arrays.asList(new Employee("101", "sunny"), new Employee("102", "Andrew"));
    beanToCsvExport(list, "file.csv");
}
```

The achieved output:

```
"eId","eName"
"101","sunny"
"102","Andrew"
```

Comment: It's working thank you but it is not switching the line. and column header is appearing as many times as i'm adding object.

Comment: Try adding a line break as: `writer.write("\n");` after writing the object.

Comment: output: "eId","eName","101","sunny""eId","eName""102","Andrew"

Comment: If you are calling `beanToCsv(object)` for every object it will write the column header every time. Instead of passing an instance of type T to `beanToCsv` pass a `List<T>` containing all the objects you want to write.

Comment: But still i need to iterate that right? it will be object again

Comment: Can you share the class of the object (type T) that you are passing to `beanToCsv`? Then I will test and post an example. :)

Comment: List is working one header is created but not changing the line. it is a simple employ class with id and name.

Comment: I have edited the answer with the code I have tested.

Comment: I've copy pasted the same code can you tell me why it's not working for me? or please send the file at kandelamanikanta@gmail.com thanks a lot for your efforts